# Using Google Sheets trying to remove all Chinese characters - possible?

Tags: google-sheets

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's an example:

```
煒靈工程 Welling Engineering Group
```

I'd like a formula to just strip out the English....

Can this even be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[^A-Z a-z]+","")`

---

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Amazing thanks so much - works great